# Find and replace URL's in database without trailing slash on end of URL

Tags: database, wordpress, url, redirect, replace

We're using WordPress for content management in our website. We have many internal and external links in our content. However, some people that placed the content made `<a href""></a>` URL's **without adding a backslash** to the end of the URL (Trailing Slash).

Example:
Find more info on `<a href="https://test.com/testpage">this website</a>`.

When people click on that link, the browser goes to that page, but redirects it to `https://test.com/testpage/`. It automatically adds an backslash to the end, which counts as a redirect by Google crawlers.

**TL;DR**
How can I replace all the URL's in my WordPress content without the backslash `(https://test.com/testpage)`, with URL's and added backslashes `(https://test.com/testpage/)`?

Comment: Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

Try This MySQL Query Work with me

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://oldurl.com', 'https://newurl.com.sa');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'https://oldurl.com', 'https://newurl.com.sa');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have about 800 different URL's which have no backslash at the end of the URL. I have to find an solution that finds all the URL's without a backslash at the end, and then adds an backslash at the end.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?